# Grease Pencil unexpected deform by lattice & armature modifier

Tags: grease-pencil, lattice

Good day!
I'm trying to use lattice modifier and armature modifier for grease pencil object.

Now I'm putting lattice modifier to grease pencil object, then put armature modifier to lattice.
But when I rotated armature bone, grease pencil object was shrink with rotate.

I tried to create new simple file as attached picture which has only 1 Bone, 1 lattice, 1 grease pencil, but this was happen also.
This deformation never happen when rotate lattice object itself. happening only when rotate lattice by parental bone.

If someone could explain what is happening, very much appreciated for me.

I'm using Blender2.93LTS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and I was able to fix it by setting the interpolation mode to "Linear" instead of "BSpline".

[image: mode]